# Older alternatives for userfaultfd() syscall in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, version, compatibility, system-calls

I want to use userfaultfd() syscall in a C program, but it is not present in older Linux kernels. What are the alternatives for userfaultfd() syscall that's also present in older version Linux kernels?
Thanks!

EDIT: What I want is, a method to get some of the main advantages of usefaultfd(), mainly handling page faults.

Comment: This API is new in linux 4.3, http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_userfaultfd.2.html, I don't think there is a alternatives, that why they create it.

Comment: I already saw that, but,  weren't there are way to handle page faults in older Linux kernels? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You could handle the segfault signal but it's way more legacy and could be hard to do with thread.

Comment: No problem. Can you please tell that in answer? I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: No, thanks, I'm not sure of these informations. You should try to search yourself, but this kind of information is hard to find.

Comment: Okay.  I will try. thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

[`mprotect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) the page with `PROT_NONE`, so all accesses fault and implement a `SIGSEGV` handler, where you handle the fault. [libsigsegv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/) abstracts away some complexity:

> GNU libsigsegv is a library for handling page faults in user mode. A page fault occurs when a program tries to access to a region of memory that is currently not available. Catching and handling a page fault is a useful technique for implementing:
>
> - pageable virtual memory,
> - memory-mapped access to persistent databases,
> - generational garbage collectors,
> - stack overflow handlers,
> - distributed shared memory,
> - ...